# Thread stuck when use java ConcurrentSkipListSet add method

Tags: java, scala, java.util.concurrent

I'm using ConcurrentSkipListSet collection to deal with concurrent operator. I find it will stuck sometimes, reproduct with this code:

```
import java.util.Comparator
import java.util.concurrent._

object SetDeadLock extends App {
  private val tasks = new ConcurrentSkipListSet[Task](new Comparator[Task](){
    override def compare(o1: Task, o2: Task): Int = {
      val compare = (o1.systemTime - o2.systemTime).toInt
      if (compare == 0) 1 else compare  //distinct same time task
    }
  })

  for(i <- 1 to 20) {
    tasks.add(Task())
    println(s"added - $i")
  }

  case class Task() {
    val systemTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  }
}
```

Output

```
added - 1
added - 2
```

It perhaps stuck at others, besides, the comparator custom sort data method especially they are same (because Set not support same element) and all `Task` is new instance, it shouldn't be conflict with others.

with `jstack` cmd, the main thread stuck

```
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap.findPredecessor(ConcurrentSkipListMap.java:685)
```

does it was a bug or I just misleading some principle?

Thanks any help or advise.

**UPDATE**
I just now try modify `if (compare == 0) 1 else compare` to `if (compare == 0) -1 else compare`, surprising, I works well!

Does anyone could clarify how it work? Source code its difficult for me(and I think many people agree with me), after all, jdk do many works for machine execute speed not for code reader.

**Finally**
To avoid the awkward situation just make some different factor to `comparator` which match `Set`'s semantics, such as appends a random value.But I think its will be better find another real suitable collection.

With a few days ago, I find a good idea to use hashCode as second verify when systemTime equals. hope helpful~

Comment: probably so fast that you end up with identical times while the comparator says same time = different. Not sure how it's implemented but I could imagine that causes some ugly loop because a < b and at the same time b < a can't be good.

Comment: @zapl, does you means it was a bug caused by `Comparator`? sleep 500 millis also has the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator is not stable.  I don't think `ConcurrentSkipListMap` promises to behave nicely when different calls give inconsistent results.  For instance, depending on how you call, you can think both a < b and b < a at the same time with your code.

Comment: I have some confuse about the means of not stable, in other words, should I define <, >, and = ? I want store has same systemTime element, as we know, `add` method will return a false if comparator result as 0.

Comment: @LoranceChen - Something is "stable" if it gives the same result each time you ask, regardless of how you ask.  In your case, if `a` and `b` have the same `systemTime` value, then `a compare b` is 1 meaning `a > b`.  But `b compare a` is _also_ 1, meaning `b > a` meaning `a < b`.  You have changed your mind about which is bigger!  If you want to break ties you must do it in a reproducible way, or algorithms that make sensible assumptions about how `<` works will break depending on implementation details that you can't see and may change from release to release of the language.

Comment: I think I have know the reason why unstable.my current solution maybe also stuck at other java version.I need a true comparable factor for `Set`.Thanks a lot.